# How does Hagrid purchase items his size?

Tags: harry-potter, hagrid

It is canon that Hagrid lives in a hut. It is full of items his size: a large bed, large cutlery, etc.

- Where do wizards generally purchase normal things?
- Where does Hagrid find things his size?

Comment: The issue with questions like this is _magic exists_; so Hagrid could just purchase regular size items and enlarge them through magical means.

Comment: Etsy? You'd be surprised what is available to Persons of Size on the interwebs.

Comment: ***Engorgio*!**

Comment: Chances are he's not the only person his size, so there may be specialised retailers.

Comment: @fez he isn't allowed to use magic

Comment: @FukaiMizumi but it's canon that he does use it, illegally and on the quiet, and gets away with it. He also lives in the grounds of a magical school whose staff sometimes help each other with magic.

Comment: We're never told. Given the size of the magical community, its likely that a lot of clothes are made by tailors using a mixture of hand-crafting and magic. Our modern muggle idea of "off the peg" clothing made in giant factories by cheap labour probably isn't a thing in the magical community. So he may just use the tailor and cobbler in Hogsmeade like everyone else. Its also possible he makes at least some of his clothes himself.

Comment: He's half giant...where do full blooded giants get their stuff?  He could probably shop in the juniors section there.

Comment: Madam Malkin's apparently does the school uniforms bespoke (no trying on of various shirts and trousers to figure out what "age" fits for Harry). And presumably clothes could come with some sort of "self sizing" spell (for when they get mailed like the dress robes).

Answer (score 6):

### He knits his socks himself and possibly other clothes as well:

We don't know where he purchases his clothing, but the possibility is raised that he knits them:

> Hagrid took up two seats and sat knitting what looked like a canary-yellow circus tent. "Still got yer letter, Harry?" he asked as he counted stitches. (Philosophers Stone)

[We don't know what he is knitting](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/172956/what-was-hagrid-knitting), but being it's very large, it's possible it's an article of clothing for himself.

In fact, specifically regarding his socks, it is explicitly stated he darns them:

> A light rain had started to fall by mid-afternoon; it was very cosy sitting by the fire, listening to the gentle patter of the drops on the window, watching Hagrid **darning his socks** and arguing with Hermione about house-elves – for he flatly refused to join S.P.E.W. when she showed him her badges.
>
> ‘It’d be doin’ ’em an unkindness, Hermione,’ he said gravely, threading a massive bone needle with thick yellow yarn.”

So we see he knits his socks (although its possible this is just a repair), and it's probable the same is true with regard to his other clothing.